# AngularJS: Display overlay with specific content

Tags: jquery, angular

Exceptionally new to Angular and attempting to avoid using jQuery in conjunction with it. (Is this a good or a bad practice?) Anyway:

1. I have two buttons on the screen, one is to show an email field in an overlay, the other is to show a password field in an overlay
2. I can achieve this with two different on click events and two different div wrappers (one which holds the email, and another that holds the password)
3. However, I feel this seems a tad inefficient

`Question`

How would I go about having one on click event for both?

For example, if I click the email button, I would like the overlay to appear with the email input field visible. If I click on the password button, I would like the overlay to appear with the password field visible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  showOverlay: boolean = false;
  emailValue: string = 'testing@email.com';


  toggleOverlay(): void {
    this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- App Component -->

<button (click)='toggleOverlay()'>Show Email Overlay</button>
<button (click)='toggleOverlay()'>Show Password Overlay</button>

<div class='overlay' *ngIf='showOverlay'>
  <input class='emailInput' [value]='emailValue'/>
  <input class='passwordInput' [value]='passwordValue'/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is:

```
<button (click)='toggleOverlay()'>Show Email Overlay</button>
<button (click)='toggleOverlay()'>Show Password Overlay</button>

<div class='overlay'>
  <input class='emailInput' [value]='emailValue' *ngIf='showOverlay'/>
  <input class='passwordInput' [value]='passwordValue' *ngIf='!showOverlay'/>
</div>
```

Other way is:

```
<button (click)='showEmail = true'>Show Email Overlay</button>
<button (click)='showEmail = false'>Show Password Overlay</button>

<div class='overlay'>
  <input class='emailInput' [value]='emailValue' *ngIf='showEmail'/>
  <input class='passwordInput' [value]='passwordValue' *ngIf='!showEmail'/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank Donathamsetti. When I copy this, the overlay is always visible. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please remove toggleOverlay() method and showOverlay variable in component. Replace <div class='overlay' *ngIf='showOverlay'> to <div class='overlay'>

Comment: Thanks again. I had already done that. The overlay is always showing with the password input field visible. I'm tempted to use jQuery as I would have this simple stuff sorted pretty quickly :P

Comment: Ok thanks. Regarding the above, shouldn't the check be on the overlay div as well as the inputs? Otherwise the overlay will always be visible, it doesn't know to hide and show. Is my thinking correct there?

Comment: Yes it should not be in overlay div

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is efficient, but it works and doesn't show the overlay all the time.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  showOverlay: boolean = false;
  showChangeEmail: boolean = false;
  showChangePassword: boolean = false;
  emailValue: string = 'test@email.com';


  changeEmail(): void {
    this.showOverlay = true;
    this.showChangeEmail = true;
  }

  changePassword(): void {
    this.showOverlay = true;
    this.showChangePassword = true;
  }

}
```

```html
<button (click)='changeEmail()'>Show Email Overlay</button>
<button (click)='changePassword()'>Show Password Overlay</button>

<div class='overlay' *ngIf='showOverlay'>
  <input class='emailInput' [value]='emailValue' *ngIf='showOverlay && showChangeEmail'/>
  <input class='passwordInput' value='********' *ngIf='showOverlay && showChangePassword'/>
</div>
```